# postgresql: syntax error for creating a function that determines the differences in dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, date, syntax-error

I would like to write a function that calculates the difference in two dates. Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION order_prep_days(ship_date DATE, order_date DATE)
returns 
'ship_date - order_date'
language sql
select pct_change(2010-08-01, 2010-06-30);
```

Then I got this error:

```
syntax error at or near "'ship_date - order_date'"
LINE 3:     'ship_date - order_date'
```

I would hugely appreciate it if someone can help me get the output without any error. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issue with your code, notably:

- the datatype of the arguments should be dates rather than numeric
- you need to declare the return type, and use the `as` keyword to before the actual code starts
- you should `select` the substraction operation
- when invoking the function, arguments need to be quoted

Consider:

```
create or replace function order_prep_days(ship_date date, order_date date)
returns integer as 'select ship_date - order_date'
language sql

select order_prep_days('2010-08-01', '2010-06-30');
```

Yields:

```
| order_prep_days |
| --------------: |
|              32 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=edc4090a5a9243b6e8b61867b77f9a35)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION order_prep_days(ship_date DATE, order_date DATE)
returns int as
   'select ship_date - order_date'
language sql
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb263)